# Is there a program or a script for one key to type another?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

I need a program that's able to have it so when I type z, it types s instead. Is there any like this? Or any type of scripting I can do myself for this to work? 
I have a Windows 7 OS PC.

Comment: it has any pattern or just random?

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?  Is this functionality specifically going to happen on a web page?

Comment: Unsure what this have to do with javascript? Maybe autohotkey or something similar would fix what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the key value and replace it with the value you'd like to replace it with.

FIDDLE Makes Z or z » S or s:
http://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/rz6ba0jt/2/

HTML:

```
<input id="target" />
```

JS:

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function(event) {

    var replaceWithKey1 = "S";
    var replaceWithKey2 = "s";

    if (event.which == 90){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + replaceWithKey1);
    }
    else if (event.which == 122){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + replaceWithKey2);
    }

});
```

FIDDLE Makes S or s » Z or z:
http://jsfiddle.net/remix1201/rz6ba0jt/1/

HTML:

```
<input id="target" />
```

JS:

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function(event) {

    var replaceWithKey1 = "Z";
    var replaceWithKey2 = "z";

    if (event.which == 83){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + replaceWithKey1);
    }
    else if (event.which == 115){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val($(this).val() + replaceWithKey2);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you want, but seems close enough -

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/